# Couchbase rereduce always false

Tags: couchbase

I'm new with Couchbase. I'm working on reduce function and realize in all of my cases, the rereduce parameters is always false. I've read document about `rereduce`. They says when the reduce function is called after the previous reduce phase, the `rereduce` is true. It's confusing me.

My question is how to get `rereduce` = true ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rereduce will become true if you have more than one server in your cluster. I'll explain on _count function example.

When you have one server both operations: map and reduce are processed on one server. I.e. if you have such array : after map: [1:null, 2:null, ... , 5:null] and you need to count them in reduce it will return 5 in one step.

But if you have more than one server map and reduce functions will be executed on each server. So you get i.e. [1:null,3:null] from first server in map, and [2:null,4:null,5:null] from another. Then reduce function will be also called on both servers and it will return [2] from first server and [3] from another. That values will be passed to reduce again on one server, so on rereduce you'll get in value param an array [[2],[3]] and here you need to add that values to get correct count.

Comment: Rereduce is set to true not only when it is coming from multiples nodes but also when the reduce function is called on a node and when the calculation is done on multiple "nodes" of the B*Tree.